# App icon for Android in Phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, icons

I have an HTML5/Javascript app, and I have used PhoneGap's build service to generate the APK file for my Android.

I successfully installed the APK file on my Android and everything is fine, except that the app icon on the phone is the default Android icon. In PhoneGap Build I uploaded my PNG file to the project under the 'Details' section, and I thought that icon was supposed to be used as your app icon? I've tried several different sizes.

Let me know if there is something else I need to be doing.

Comment: 1. This is not a duplicate - the referenced topic discusses Eclipse app, while this one is focused on PhoneGap build on the cloud.

2. I've found the answer here: http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/configuring_icons_and_splash.md.html#Icons%20and%20Splash%20Screens

-> "The default icon must be named icon.png and must reside in the root of your application folder."

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the Phone Gap the following should contain

> www_android\res\values\strings.xml - contains the name of the app
>   www_android\res\drawable-hdpi - contains a 57x57 pixel icon
>   www_android\res\drawable-hdpi - contains a 57x57 pixel icon
>   www_android\res\drawable-hdpi - contains a 57x57 pixel icon

[Source](http://www.nsbasic.com/app/tutorials/TT12.htm) (Step 12)

**Alternatively**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0" id="com.nitobi.johngarrett" version="1.0">
<name>John Garrett Drinking Game</name> 
<description>
If you're watching a Canucks game, you need play this.
</description> 
<author href="http://www.nitobi.com" email="support@nitobi.com">
Tim Kim, Ryan Betts, Fil Maj
</author> 
<icon src="img/beer_72.png" width="72" height="72" />
<icon src="img/beer_48.png" width="48" height="48" />
<icon src="img/beer_36.png" width="36" height="36" />
</widget>
```

[Source](http://blogs.nitobi.com/fil/2011/03/15/phonegap-build-icon-support-for-android/)

Comment: Where exactly do you mean? Somewhere in the APK file or somewhere in my folder prior to upload?

Comment: The alternative solution you provided worked.

Comment: In order for the first option to work (without PhoneGap build), you need to make sure that if you use, e.g., "icon.png" as a file name you change the android:icon attribute in your AndroidManifest.xml file to android:icon="@drawable/icon"

Comment: The first solution worked for me, although the path is a little different (my icons were in `assets/www/res/icon/android`, so I just replaced those). *However* I had to perform a "clean" / rebuild on the project before the APK was updated with the new icon. FYI.

Comment: Alternative works well, thnks +1.

Comment: Both links are dead.

Answer (score 1):

None of the above answers worked but I figured it out how. Create a png icon and name it "icon.png" and simply place the image under "Project_Folder/res/drawable-hdpi/", where Project_Folder is your PhoneGap application folder.

Hope that helps.

Comment: mine was here "Project_Folder/platforms/android/bin/res/crunch