# Application icon in Google Play

Tags: cordova, google-play

I recently built an app using PhoneGapBuild.
When I uploaded my app to Google Play, the application icon in the list is the default phonegap one:

[image]

I have these icon resources listed in my config.xml file:

```
<icon src="assets/icons/android/icon36.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="ldpi" />
<icon src="assets/icons/android/icon48.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="mdpi" />
<icon src="assets/icons/android/icon72.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="hdpi" />
<icon src="assets/icons/android/icon96.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="xhdpi" />
```

But it doesnt seem to work properly.

Do I need to add a new entry to the config.xml or is it something else?

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/a/8230927/759019

Comment: No change using this. That question seems to refer to the icon on the device though, not in Google Play.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When adding icons in PhoneGap, or when working with paths in general, please check the path names are correct before posting to StackOverflow and making a fool of yourself!

Silly me!

Answer (score 1):

I have not used PhoneGap myself, so I don't know if there is a specific way to check that. However, there is a general method. You can use **[apktool](http://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/)** to show resources in your apk, change them, and then recompile.

See my answer [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11418998/759019).

Comment: This is useful and shows the default phonegap icons in the drawable fodler. So it seems like the build isnt working properly. Thanks